# How do I asynchronously map values onto a function with threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11

I'm trying to learn how to execute "embarrassingly" parallel tasks in C++11. A common pattern I come across is to get the result of a function when evaluated over a range of values, similar to calling python's [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool). I've written a minimal example that shows what I know how to do, namely call a single process and wait for the result. How can I "map" this call asynchronously and wait until all values are done? Ideally, I'd like the results in a vector of the same length and order as the original.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double square_add(double x, double y) { return x*x+y; }

int main() {
  vector<double> A = {1,2,3,4,5};

  // Single evaluation
  auto single_result = std::async(square_add,A[2],3);
  cout << "Evaluating a single index " << single_result.get() << endl;

  // Blocking map
  for(auto &x:A) {
    auto blocking_result = std::async(square_add,x,3);
    cout << "Evaluating a single index " << blocking_result.get() << endl;
  }

  // Non-blocking map?

  return 0;
}
```

Note: to get this code to compile with `gcc` I need the `-pthreads` flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::async returns a future, so you can store them in a vector for later consumption:

```
std::vector<std::future<double>> future_doubles;
future_doubles.reserve(A.size());
for (auto& x : A) {
    // Might block, but also might not.
    future_doubles.push_back(std::async(square_add, x, 3));
}

// Now block on all of them one at a time.
for (auto& f_d : future_doubles) {
    std::cout << f_d.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Now the above code might or might not run asynchronously. It's up to the implementation/system to decide whether it's worth it to perform the task asynchronously or not. If you want to force it to run in separate threads, you can pass an optional launch_policy to std::async, changing the call to

```
future_doubles.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, square_add, x, 3));
```

For more info on `std::async` and the various policies, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: Who or what determines if the block will launch asynchronously, the compiler or the system?

Comment: I'm not quite sure actually. I would personally leave it up to the compiler/system unless I absolutely require them to run in separate threads. Sometimes it's faster to just blitz through them all in the simple loop.

Comment: Where's my head at? Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a `std::vector<std::future<void>>` plus a `std::vector<double>` for the results.

Comment: @Dyp Do you mind elaborating on that? I'm not quite sure that I follow. What does making a `future<void>` get you that `future<double>` does not?

Comment: @Hooked Actually, the idea was to provide a `std::vector<double>` with results in it. If you directly need this type or need to iterate over the results quickly, it might be better to have *a structure of arrays instead of an array of structures* (here: two vectors of different types instead of one vector of a composite type).

Comment: @Dyp That seems _useful_ and possibly faster! The code above _works_ and answers the question, but I would love to see how you would do it. If you post another answer I'll upvote it, or if you think it's fodder for another question I can keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical / simpler way [has already been shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125562/420683) by [bstamour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154744/bstamour). There's an alternative however, if iteration speed is critical and/or the resulting type has to be `std::vector<double>`:

```
std::vector<double> results(A.size());
std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    futures.reserve(A.size());                  // second allocation

auto store_result = [](double& result, double x, double y)
                    { result = square_add(x, y); };
// non-capturing lambda might give better performance, test it

// launch the async operations
for(int i = 0; i != A.size(); ++i)
    futures.emplace_back(std::async(store_result, std::ref(results[i]), A[i], 3));

// wait for all results to become ready
for(auto& e : futures)
    e.get();

// results are in the `results` vector
for(auto const& e : results)
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
```

---

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double square_add(double x, double y) { return x*x+y; }

int main() {
  vector<double> A = {1,2,3,4,5};

  // Single evaluation
  std::cout << "single evaluation" << std::endl;
  auto single_result = std::async(square_add,A[2],3);
  cout << "Evaluating a single index " << single_result.get() << endl;

  // Blocking map
  std::cout << "\n\n";
  std::cout << "blocking map" << std::endl;
  for(auto &x:A) {
    auto blocking_result = std::async(square_add,x,3);
    cout << "Evaluating a single index " << blocking_result.get() << endl;
  }

  // Non-blocking map?

    // bstamour's solution:
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "bstamour's solution" << std::endl;
    {
        std::vector<std::future<double>> future_doubles;
        future_doubles.reserve(A.size());
        for (auto& x : A) {
            // Might block, but also might not.
            future_doubles.push_back(std::async(square_add, x, 3));
        }

        // Now block on all of them one at a time.
        for (auto& f_d : future_doubles) {
            std::cout << f_d.get() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // DyP's solution
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "DyP's solution" << std::endl;
    {
        std::vector<double> results(A.size());
        std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
        futures.reserve(A.size());                  // second allocation
        auto store_result = [](double& result, double x, double y) { result = square_add(x, y); };
        for(int i = 0; i != A.size(); ++i)
            futures.emplace_back( std::async(store_result, std::ref(results[i]), A[i], 3) );

        for(auto& e : futures)
            e.get();

        for(auto const& e : results)
            std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this shows an old problem: You can't access uninitialized elements of a `std::vector` w/o invoking UB :/ (not even writing to them). The ctor of the vector here initializes the doubles. It's one of the few reasons IMO to still use `std::unique_ptr<double[]> results{ new double[A.size()] };`

Comment: Thank you very much! Having a complete answer like this is useful to pour over, now at least I know what library calls I should be looking at.