# What is the best way to asynchronously fill a std::map in C++?

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, insert, parallel-processing, stdmap

I'm trying to figure out the "best" way to fill a **std::map** in C++11 with values read from a text file. The solution for that problem should work with STL only.

There actually is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19125371/2852046) of my question on SO since the answers drifted off-topic by targeting std::vector instead of std::map, I'm rephrasing it following [this advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48113/305249) from meta SO in hope to get some answers to the actual question. I've spotted two approaches/ideas so far:

1. **Use std::fill**:
   As far as I understand STL does offer [*(experimental)* parallel](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing#fill) versions of fill but apparently those do not work with maps since std::fill expects arguments to meet the "ForwardIterator" requirements.
2. **std::async/std:future**:
   I'm actually unsure if it is a good idea or for that matter even possible to use futures with maps. Since a map is supposed to have a unique keyset and multiple futures theoretically could be added before having an actual key value. In this case will std::map stall the concurrent inserts till the future with undetermined key value has been decided?

Is there any practice of asynchronously loading maps (with values from a text file)? Which solution is considered safe?

Comment: Do you want to fill the map with multiple threads concurrently, or fill the map and concurrently read it (with another thread), or fill the map with some thread while doing something else with your "main" thread?

Comment: There is absolutely no way whatsoever to populate `std::map` concurrently or asynchronously.

Comment: @dyp: The map is supposed to be an index. The index should be asynchronously filled, but before any read access occurrs the complete index has been loaded. So there is no need to do anything *else* then adding std::pairs to the map but it would be great if adding the entries to the map would work in parallel. Sth. like std::async(map.insert(std::future...

Comment: Sounds like a pointer to the map should be returned from a future. Then there's no way to access it at all until the background thread has created it.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: No need for a return value the map is member of the index database class. The map is basically a list of unique keys (id values), which is assigned a list (vector) of foreign keys related to that unique key. The problem is the index file has a size of multiple GByte's so what happens when loading it is one of the CPU cores goes to 100% and the rest is pretty much idling, together with the HDD - stalling the load unnecessarily. If I could distribute the memory allocation and index object creation among threads this would speed things up.

Comment: The Standard Library containers are not designed for concurrent modification. If the creation of the "index objects" is a bottleneck that can be overcome by parallelisation, you could try creating one map per thread and then merge them (using a new map and its `insert` member function that takes a hint). This is not optimal because the tree structure is not reused (e.g. node allocations). You could improve memory allocation performance for the merge map by using a custom allocator: [to be continued]

Comment: [continued] You know the size of the merge map after each thread has created its map, and fragmentation isn't an issue (probably), so a simple stack allocator (the stack data structure, not the thread's Stack) could be used.

Comment: @dyp Yes I already assumed that it was impossible with the map still wanted to check back here to see if I had missed sth. I'll probably also have a look into techiques used in video game programming for asset management I assume solutions there will have to deal with similar problems. Thanks for your ideas on the issue.

Comment: If you just want to accumulate results "for later" you can [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) the pairs for adding in sequence

Comment: If you consider the nature of the underlying binary tree beneath a `std::map` it's hard to envisage how it could be segmented for parallelisation.  Hash-maps have more possibilities here as locking can be localised and at various levels of granularity.